# How to denote a "work in progress" in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

What is the correct way to reference in BibTeX an article that has no title yet?  All the information I have right now is a list of authors (not even certain), a year (perhaps), and the knowledge of what I am going to write in that article.

The bib entry I currently use is

```
@misc{work-in-progress,
 author    = "{Work in progress}",
}
```

because it prints the right thing (`Work in progress.`) in the bibliography using the style I use.  However, it seems wrong, and surely won't always be displayed in a sensible way if I change the style.  Also, BibTeX complains that the `howpublished` field is missing.

Comment: If `howpublished` has no meaning, then `@unpublished` would be more apt.

Comment: @egreg According to the BibTeX manual (and my test) `@unpublished` requires the fields `author`, `title` and `note`, while `@misc` should require none of the fields.  Since I don't know the title (I could produce a reasonable guess, but I'd rather not), it seems I'm stuck with `@misc`.  But thanks for pointing me to `@unpublished` as I had shamefully not checked the manual.

Comment: May I ask what is the reason for pointing to an not jet written work? I would -- if possible -- not refer to it until I know a titel or I would create an working title and would use it with the remark "working title (can be changed): ..." .

Comment: I agree with Kurt; from your description (still no title, authors yet to determine, uncertainty about date), it's seems that there's no point in building a bibliographical entry for this work (at least not yet). You can simply add a mention to this work in the body of the document.

Comment: I think this needs the `@unicorn` entry type.

Comment: Instead of a pointless footnote, I can prefer this entry in the bibliography. Also the content is not always scientific so to be able to do this properly is important in my opinion.